# execute_script throws no exception but file not created

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Trying to create a function to streamline some automation.

When the javascript is called with the arguments directly it works perfectly and the file is created.

```
browser.execute_script("HAR.clear({token: \"abcd\"})")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("B").click()
browser.execute_script("HAR.triggerExport({token: \"abcd\", fileName: \"name_of_file\"}).then(result => {})")
```

When i try to pass it as a variable, there are no errors but the har file is not created.

Call:

```
simple_find("B",'\\"name_of_file\\"')
```

Function:

```
def simple_find (element, filename):
    browser.execute_script("HAR.clear({token: \"abcd\"})")
    browser.find_element_by_link_text(element).click()
    options = '{token: \\"abcd\\", fileName: '+filename+'}'
    ret=browser.execute_script("HAR.triggerExport(arguments[0]).then(result => {});return arguments[0]",options)
    print ret
```

I added the return piece to help debug what is being passed and here is the output:

```
C:>python firefox-Manage.py 
{token: \"abcd\", fileName: \"name_of_file\"}
```

It looks exactly like the call made earlier with the exception of the file not being created. What am I missing?

java version is: 1.8.0_66
selenium version is: 2.48.2
python version is: 2.7.10

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options object created from Python looks malformed. There's no reason to surround the values with `\\"`:

```
options = '{token: \\"abcd\\", fileName: '+filename+'}'
```

My guess would be you want to pass a dictionary directly to selenium instead of a string:

```
options = {'token': "abcd", 'fileName': filename}
```